# NodeJS synchronous request from mongoose

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

I'm developing a website in NodeJS with Mongo. Part of the website has url localhost/api/ and returns some JSON, it works fine for fetching from clientside. Now I want to work with these data from server (to prerender it). Basically, I have a function which should return the result from the API part. It looks like this:

```
request('http://localhost:8000/api/', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    return body // return the JSON array from API which works OK
  }
})
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work and only returns "500: TypeError: Cannot call method 'map' of undefined at App". The code simply doesn't have the value at the moment it renders, so I would ideally like to make the function somehow synchronous as I'm used to from other languages.

If I return the JSON array I need directly from the function (without asking for it from request module), it works. Therefore, I know that the problem comes from my wrong usage of asynschronous programming. What would you recommend as a solution? (I could also ask the mongo directly, not via request, but that's not the problem now - I tried and it was the same).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone was interested.. I have solved this problem quickly with Promises.  The function which waits for the result of request expects a Promise, which is made in the request call.